# Is there a way to put content on top of youtube's full screen mode?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

I'm using the [Youtube iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

I have a need to put content on top of the youtube iframe player. Example: when a video finishes, I want to show options for the next video to play. I've accomplished this in non-full screen mode using z-index and the  wmode: "transparent" option (required to make it work in IE) like so:

```
 player = new YT.Player('show', {
      height: '540',
      width: '960',
      videoId: firstID,
      playerVars: { rel:0,modestbranding:1, wmode: "transparent" },
      events: {
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }

    });
```

This works, however, when the user clicks the "full screen" button, the content is hidden behind the youtube iframe... I can't seem to position content on top of full screen mode. The same thing happens with the vimeo player using the vimeo api but I suppose that's another can of worms. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each browser implements HTML5 fullscreen video a bit differently; for example, on Chrome you end up with an iframe whose z-index is 2147483647. If you set the z-index of your content higher than that, it may achieve what you want.

However, it's important to note that Flash fullscreen bypasses the browser altogether, so I'm not sure that you'll find a solution that meets all use cases. Theoretically you could restrict your app to HTML5 videos only, and then deal with that, but it may not be feasible for you.

I might also (in the interest of full discussion, FWIW) point out that, as far as YouTube goes, the TOS might restrict what you're trying to do:

https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

(section 4F).

Comment: I don't see how what I'm doing is against TOS. Let me explain what I'm doing:
* Display a countdown when a video ends which says "next video playing in 3 .. 2 ... 1.
* Automatically play next video when the countdown is over
* When the playlist has ended, display a message that says "you've finished blah blah" with a thumbnail of the video and a like button.

How is that against tos? I don't see how that could be interpreted as "modifying, building upon, or blocking any portion or functionality of the Embeddable Player."

Comment: I guess a lot of the determination would be whether or not you're overlaying the actual player (for example, covering up the YouTube logo, changing the look of the play button, adding your own captions or ads over the top of videos). In your case, if the video is already done, you may be fine ... but a lot of the determination of that would be in your implementation. I can't speak to who would make that decision, though. In any case, I've edited the 'answer' part of my post above to be more clear about how you might get this to actually work; let me know if it's helpful!

Comment: Thanks. It's sort of a gray area - I'm not covering any of the functionality of the player, just the video windows itself after the video finishes playing.  But what I'm doing could still easily be interpreted as "blocking any portion" of the player.. so I think to be on the safe side, I'll put my content below the player. Thanks for your comment as I would have otherwise never known I was (possibly) violating YT TOS.